# Fortran select a vector by indicating its name

Tags: arrays, fortran

In a program coded in F90, I have a set of 11 vectors, each of a size (7), with names going from "S1" to "S11".
**I need to be able to read a number of elements from one vector, by giving the name of this latter.**
Although this problem seems an elementary one, with my beginner level, I am unable to find a way to code it...

any help ?

Answer (score 4):

When a Fortran program executes it doesn't really have the information available to identify a variable based on the value of a string containing the name of a variable.  You could write a sequence of `if` statements such as

```
if (mystr=='S1') x = s1
if (mystr=='S2') x = s2
...
```

You could pretty this up a bit with a `select case` construction

```
select case (mystr)
case ('S1')
    x = s1
case ('S2')
    x = s2
...
```

but that may not appeal much more.

A better approach by far would be to declare your vectors as elements of a rank-2 array:

```
real, dimension(11,7) :: s
```

and you can then do all sorts of computations, at run-time, to select the vector you want

```
myrow = an_expression_returning_an_integer_between_1_and_11_inclusive
x = s(myrow,:)
```